# PHP Soap client call

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, request

I am desperate. I am trying to call soap request from php like this xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:hot="http://hotelconcepts.com/">   <soapenv:Header>
  <hot:Authentication>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:User>?</hot:User>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:Password>?</hot:Password>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:CrsProperty>?</hot:CrsProperty>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:VendorId>?</hot:VendorId>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:Version>?</hot:Version>
  </hot:Authentication>   
</soapenv:Header>   
<soapenv:Body>
  <hot:CwiPackageAvailabilityDetails>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:PropertyCode>?</hot:PropertyCode>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:Packages>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <hot:string>?</hot:string>
     </hot:Packages>
     <hot:StartDate>?</hot:StartDate>
     <hot:EndDate>?</hot:EndDate>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:Adults>0</hot:Adults>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:Children>0</hot:Children>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:Infants>0</hot:Infants>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <hot:Nights>0</hot:Nights>
  </hot:CwiPackageAvailabilityDetails>
```

I am trying something like this, but i don´t know how to imitate this xml request by php soap client.

```
    $client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl);

    $headers = array(
        "Authentication" => array(
            "User" => $this->user,
            "Password" => $this->pass,
            "CrsProperty" => $this->crsProperty
        )
    );

    $client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);

    /* Set your parameters for the request */
    $params = array(
        "User" => $this->user,
        "Password" => $this->pass,
        "CrsProperty" => $this->crsProperty,
        "PropertyCode" => $this->propertyCode,
        "StartDate" => $startDate,
        "EndDate" => $endDate,
        "Adults" => $adults,
        "Children" => $children,

    );
    try {
        /* Invoke webservice method with your parameters, in this case: Function1 */
        $response = $client->__soapCall("CwiPackageAvailabilityDetails", array($params, $headers));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
        echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
    /* Print webservice response */
    var_dump($response);
}
```

But i get only this message: Server was unable to process request. ---> Not authenticated for property

Thank you for any help

Comment: Save yourself a lot of pain and suffering and use [`wsdl2phpgenerator`](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator)

Comment: I was trying but no luck..

Comment: is VendorID a GUID by any chance?

Comment: Since namespaces are used your array syntax for the header will not work. You should assemble your soap header with the `SoapVar` object and set it properly with `SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders`.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to use the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) as if the header is well declared in the WSDL, then you'll have the appropriate method to set it before sending the request. Every parameter is represented by a generated class such as every operation within a proper ServiceType class.